# What is my server if I run my .NET app using dotnet executable?

Tags: c#, .net

If I publish my .NET API on Windows, I would see a `Web.config` file being generate for me and I can publish it to IIS.

But now I'm publishing on Linux.

I use `dotnet publish -o /path/to/publish` to publish my project, and then I use `dotnet Project.dll` to run my project. Then I put it behind an Nginx reverse proxy.

What is my web server in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=linux), even in Windows IIS can be configured to simply act as a reverse proxy for Kestrel.